# SATA devices not showing up as bootable devices after lightning strike but they do work

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, bios

Lightning stuck my house last night and forced every electric thing on my house to shut down.

Thankfully, my PC is not broken (at least the main components I guess) and when I tried to turn it back on, instead of it booting to Linux as it was supposed to, my BIOS showed up and my whole UEFI boot order was reset.

I set up the boot order back again with UEFI Hard Disk as #1 but it says that no Bootable Device was found and my Linux system doesnt appear on Boot override nor in the Boot order, however if I switch to LEGACY+UEFI the SSD and HDD showed up but with no UEFI prefix nor the name of my install (arch)

Both the SSD and HDD are working cause they are being detected in the BIOS System Status tab, and I can mount, chroot and run stuff such as ls, cd, neofetch, etc… and everything works as expected (booting via USB with archiso installation thing)

Secure Boot is disabled and GRUB is installed in the SSD:

- **Motherboard**: MSI H110M PRO-VH PLUS
- **BIOS**: MSI Click Bios (E7A15IMS.170)

Comment: May be the BIOS configuration settings in battery backed SRAM were affected by the lightning? I would recommend to reset BIOS settings by loading optimized defaults and then rebuild your BIOS configuration.

Comment: nope, it still doesn’t work, and when I force it to use the SSD on LEGACY+UEFI it says Reboot and Select proper Boot device, imma try switching to Windows and see if I can install an MBR Arch iso, cause its not letting me do anything on UEFI with the SATA devices at all

Comment: If the data on the drives is accessible when booting from USB, I'd copy it off the drives before trying to recover them. Just in case.

Comment: oh I dont really care about the data since all I do on my PC is programming (and pushing to git) and watching Netflix but what im kinda worried about is that I might have to get another motherboard/drives

Comment: Ahhh... by your telling it looks to me like just the boot partition is corrupt. If the data is truly disposable I wouldn't even bother trying to recover it, unless just for the sake of trying :-D I'd I'd just try to partition, format, install some quick OS, see what some drive test tool says, not necessarily in that or any significant order, just "let's see if we can still get some life out of these" :-D "Maybe if I just leave that first 10MB unpartitioned..." (me 2wk ago doing exactly that - it worked :-D)

Comment: i tried installing arch again on my hdd but it wasnt detecting it, imma try leaving some MB unpartitioned just to check if that helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ended up reinstalling Arch, making /dev/sdb (my SSD partition) a GPT one, used systemd-boot and grub and it seems to be working now…

I dont really know what was the problem but using efibootmgr and setting up systemd-boot somehow made grub work again

This post helped me a lot https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219587